# Certificate cannot be resolved by PKIXValidator

Tags: java, ssl, connection, certificate

I am facing an issue where a TLS certificate (wildcard cert) is not resolved to a valid root cert in Java. Browsers (Firefox, Chrome) resolve it to be valid but not Java driven programs. We use a wildcart cert in our case.

```
certpath: Constraints: ...
...

...

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.llorllale.youtrack.api.DefaultProjects.get(DefaultProjects.java:80)
    at com.company.youtrack.Main.main(Main.java:121)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 31 more
```

**EDIT**
I am running a YouTrack server inside our company network, not accessible from the internet. I configured the immediate certificate chain including the root certificate. But sadly the root certificate itself is not returned (tested it with openssl s_client).

I also like to mention that the server certificate is a wildcard certificate. I do not really know if that could lead to problems during verification...

**EDIT**

I know it is not best practice to return the self-signed root. Although I found comments throughout my research by people that state that sometimes it is necessary. I don't really know why it is necesssary to be sure... I analyzed code in PKIXValidator and it seemed to me that the validator is resolving the chain until it receives a cert whereby the issuer is equal to the subject. My problem is (as I analyzed with openssl s_client) that the server only returns the server cert and the 1st intermediate cert. But there's a 2nd intermediate cert and a root in addition. I filed a bug at youtrack. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-66316. There are comments which I did not made publicly available because of internals. When I resolved the issue, I will report the solution here. In the meanwhile I like to leave the issue open here.

Comment: I sadly cannot post more details because of stackoverflow restriction. Either it is SMAP or it is too long or it is too short. wtf...

Comment: I wanted to submit details to my issue but sadly StackOverflow said that my post includes too much code... However I wanted to post "certpath" debug info but StackOverflow didn't let me to... Either I was identified as SPAM, or Info is too short or code (textual log info) is too long. I am getting crazy!

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the root certificate?

Comment: What cacert file are you telling java to use to validate certs? That file should have the public certs listed in your browsers to presumably work.

Comment: The root cert is USERtrust RSA certification authority, serial 01:FD:6D:30:FC:A3:CA:51:A8:1B:BC:C4:0E:35:03:2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers use certificate AIA information while Java/Linux do not (by default).  Your server in question may be configured to provide the certificate but not the certificates up to a trust anchor recognized by your Java application.  openssl (s_client) or https://certcheckerapp.com/ can help you see what the server is actually returning.

Comment: Thank's Toby for your answer to the issue. I checked the sent certificate chain with openssl s_client and I saw that all certificates were returned except the root certificate. Could that be a problem? The weird thing is that I configured a chain on the server including the root certificate but as I said, this root is not returned. I am running a YouTrack server inside a company network, not accessible from the internet. I also like to mention that I have installed a wildcard server certificate. Could that also lead to problems?

Comment: Servers typically shouldn't return the (self-signed) trust anchors since they don't help prove trust.  If the root certificate which signs the last certificate in the chain is in your app's trust store, your app should trust it.  Wildcard shouldn't be an issue assuming it is a SAN (don't think it is possible in the DN) and your dns is covered by the wildcard.  Are you sure the trust anchor for that server/chain is in your JRE trust store?

Comment: I know it is not best practice to return the self-signed root. Although I found comments throughout my research by people that state that sometimes it is necessary. I don't really know why it is necesssary to be sure... I analyzed code in PKIXValidator and it seemed to me that the validator is resolving the chain until it receives a cert whereby the issuer is equal to the subject. My problem is (as I analyzed with openssl s_client) that the server only returns the server cert and the 1st intermediate cert. But there's a 2nd intermediate cert and a root in addition. I filed a bug at youtrack.